# button is not enabling after filling all input in form

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have developed a form where the submit button will be enabled when all input fields are filled out by the user. My problem is that the submit button is not being enabled. I am using jQuery.

```js
var UserCampusName = "0";
var EmpID = null;
var FirstName = null;
var LastName = null;
var mobileNo = null;
var EmpEmail = null;
var userRoles = "0";

$('#SubmitUserRole').attr('disabled', 'disabled');

$(function () {
    $("#userRoleForm").hover(function(){
        UserCampusName = $('#UserCampus').val()
        EmpID = $('#UserEmpID').val()
        FirstName = $('#UserEmpFirstName').val()
        LastName = $('#UserEmpLastName').val()
        mobileNo = $('#UserEmpMobileNo').val()
        EmpEmail = $('#UserEmpEmail').val()
        userRoles = $('#Roles').val()
        
        if ((FirstName.length > 0) && (LastName.length > 0) && (mobileNo.length > 0) && (EmpEmail.length > 0) && (EmpID.length > 0) && (userRoles != 0) && (UserCampusName != 0)) {
            $('#SubmitUserRole').removeAttr('disabled');
        }
        else {
            $('#SubmitUserRole').attr('disabled', 'disabled');
        }
    })
})
```

```html
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.8.2.min.js"></script>

<form role="form" class="form-horizontal form-bordered" id="userRoleForm">
    <center>
        <h2>User Roles & Privileges Set-up</h2></center>
    <div class="form-group">
        <label class="label1 col-md-4">Select department <span class="required"> * </span> </label>
        <div class="col-md-7">
            <select class="form-control" id="UserCampus" data-placeholder="Select" tabindex="1">
                <option value="Category 0" default disabled selected>--Select--</option>
            </select>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
        <label class="label1 col-md-4">Enter the employee id <span class="required"> * </span> </label>
        <div class="col-md-7">
            <input id="UserEmpID" type="text" class="form-control" />
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
        <label class="label1 col-md-4">Enter First Name <span class="required"> * </span> </label>
        <div class="col-md-7">
            <input id="UserEmpFirstName" type="text" class="form-control"/>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
        <label class="label1 col-md-4">Enter Middle Name </label>
        <div class="col-md-7">
            <input id="UserEmpMiddleName" type="text" class="form-control"/>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
        <label class="label1 col-md-4">Enter Last Name <span class="required"> * </span> </label>
        <div class="col-md-7">
            <input id="UserEmpLastName" type="text" class="form-control"/>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
        <label class="label1 col-md-4">Enter Mobile Number <span class="required"> * </span> </label>
        <div class="col-md-7">
            <input id="UserEmpMobileNo" type="text" class="form-control allownumericwithoutdecimal"/>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
        <label class="label1 col-md-4">Enter Email Id <span class="required"> * </span> </label>
        <div class="col-md-7">
            <input id="UserEmpEmail" type="Email" class="form-control"/>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
        <label class="label1 col-md-4">Select the applicable user role & privileges <span class="required"> * </span> </label>
        <div class="col-md-7">
            <select id="Roles" style="width:100%;" data-placeholder="Select an option" multiple> </select>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
        <button class="btn btn-primary" id="SubmitUserRole" type="button">submit User</button>
    </div>
</form>
```

Please help me to solve this issue.

Comment: it's working fine. so what's your problem? (hover required to enable-disable)

Comment: button is enabled when i am filling all inputs

Comment: You need to use other event to trigger the disable/enable instead of hover. In `hover` only when the mouse exiting the form then you will see the button get enabled. Here you expect the button to be enabled when input is change. You need to capture the change event.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Fill all fields and click submit. it is working**

```js
var UserCampusName = "0";
 var EmpID = null;
 var FirstName = null;
 var LastName = null;
 var mobileNo = null;
 var EmpEmail = null;
 var userRoles = "0";
 
 
 $('#SubmitUserRole').attr('disabled', 'disabled');
 
 $(function () {
  $("#userRoleForm").hover(function(){
   UserCampusName = $('#UserCampus').val()
   EmpID = $('#UserEmpID').val()
   FirstName = $('#UserEmpFirstName').val()
   LastName = $('#UserEmpLastName').val()
   mobileNo = $('#UserEmpMobileNo').val()
   EmpEmail = $('#UserEmpEmail').val()
   userRoles = $('#Roles').val()
   
   if ((FirstName.length > 0) && (LastName.length > 0) && (mobileNo.length > 0) && (EmpEmail.length > 0) && (EmpID.length > 0) && (userRoles != 0) && (UserCampusName != 0)) {
    $('#SubmitUserRole').removeAttr('disabled');
   }
   else {
    $('#SubmitUserRole').attr('disabled', 'disabled');
   }
   })
 })
```

```html
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.8.2.min.js"></script>

<form role="form" class="form-horizontal form-bordered" id="userRoleForm">
  <center>
   <h2>User Roles & Privileges Set-up</h2></center>
  <div class="form-group">
   <label class="label1 col-md-4">Select department <span class="required"> * </span> </label>
   <div class="col-md-7">
         <select class="form-control" id="UserCampus" data-placeholder="Select" tabindex="1">
    <option value="Category 0" default disabled selected>--Select--</option>
    
   </select>
    
   
   </div>
  </div>
  <div class="form-group">
   <label class="label1 col-md-4">Enter the employee id <span class="required"> * </span> </label>
   <div class="col-md-7">

    <input id="UserEmpID" type="text" class="form-control" />
   
   </div>
  </div>
  <div class="form-group">
   <label class="label1 col-md-4">Enter First Name <span class="required"> * </span> </label>
   <div class="col-md-7">

    <input id="UserEmpFirstName" type="text" class="form-control"/> 
   
   
   </div>
  </div>
  <div class="form-group">
   <label class="label1 col-md-4">Enter Middle Name </label>
   <div class="col-md-7">

    <input id="UserEmpMiddleName" type="text" class="form-control"/> 
   
   
   </div>
  </div>
  <div class="form-group">
   <label class="label1 col-md-4">Enter Last Name <span class="required"> * </span> </label>
   <div class="col-md-7">

    <input id="UserEmpLastName" type="text" class="form-control"/> 
   
   
   </div>
  </div>
  <div class="form-group">
   <label class="label1 col-md-4">Enter Mobile Number <span class="required"> * </span> </label>
   <div class="col-md-7">

    <input id="UserEmpMobileNo" type="text" class="form-control allownumericwithoutdecimal"/> 
   
   
   </div>
  </div>
  <div class="form-group">
   <label class="label1 col-md-4">Enter Email Id <span class="required"> * </span> </label>
   <div class="col-md-7">

    <input id="UserEmpEmail" type="Email" class="form-control"/> 
   
   
   </div>
  </div>
  <div class="form-group">
   <label class="label1 col-md-4">Select the applicable user role & privileges <span class="required"> * </span> </label>
   <div class="col-md-7">
    <textarea type="textarea" rowspan="5"> </textarea>
   </div>
  </div>
  
  <div class="form-group">
   <button class="btn btn-primary" id="SubmitUserRole" type="button">submit User</button>
  </div>
 
</form>
```

Comment: face the same proble.
Your code save my life thanks for sharing.

Answer (score 0):

Try with following :

**HTML**

```
<form role="form" class="form-horizontal form-bordered" id="userRoleForm">
   <center>
      <h2>User Roles & Privileges Set-up</h2>
   </center>
   <div class="form-group">
      <label class="label1 col-md-4">Select department <span class="required"> * </span> </label>
      <div class="col-md-7">
         <select class="form-control" id="UserCampus" data-placeholder="Select" tabindex="1">
            <option value="0">--Select--</option>
            <option value="1">Admin</option>
         </select>
      </div>
   </div>
   <div class="form-group">
      <label class="label1 col-md-4">Enter the employee id <span class="required"> * </span> </label>
      <div class="col-md-7">
         <input id="UserEmpID" type="text" class="form-control" />
      </div>
   </div>
   <div class="form-group">
      <label class="label1 col-md-4">Enter First Name <span class="required"> * </span> </label>
      <div class="col-md-7">
         <input id="UserEmpFirstName" type="text" class="form-control"/> 
      </div>
   </div>
   <div class="form-group">
      <label class="label1 col-md-4">Enter Middle Name </label>
      <div class="col-md-7">
         <input id="UserEmpMiddleName" type="text" class="form-control"/> 
      </div>
   </div>
   <div class="form-group">
      <label class="label1 col-md-4">Enter Last Name <span class="required"> * </span> </label>
      <div class="col-md-7">
         <input id="UserEmpLastName" type="text" class="form-control"/> 
      </div>
   </div>
   <div class="form-group">
      <label class="label1 col-md-4">Enter Mobile Number <span class="required"> * </span> </label>
      <div class="col-md-7">
         <input id="UserEmpMobileNo" type="text" class="form-control allownumericwithoutdecimal"/> 
      </div>
   </div>
   <div class="form-group">
      <label class="label1 col-md-4">Enter Email Id <span class="required"> * </span> </label>
      <div class="col-md-7">
         <input id="UserEmpEmail" type="Email" class="form-control"/> 
      </div>
   </div>
   <div class="form-group">
      <label class="label1 col-md-4">Select the applicable user role & privileges <span class="required"> * </span> </label>
      <div class="col-md-7">
         <textarea type="textarea" rowspan="5"> </textarea>
      </div>
   </div>
   <div class="form-group">
      <button class="btn btn-primary" id="SubmitUserRole" type="button" disabled="disabled">submit User</button>
   </div>
</form>
```

**SCRIPT**

```
$(function(){
    $('body').on('keyup change','#userRoleForm input, #userRoleForm select',function(){
        var UserCampusName = $('#UserCampus').val()
        var EmpID = $('#UserEmpID').val()
        var FirstName = $('#UserEmpFirstName').val()
        var LastName = $('#UserEmpLastName').val()
        var mobileNo = $('#UserEmpMobileNo').val()
        var EmpEmail = $('#UserEmpEmail').val()


        if ((FirstName.length > 0) && (LastName.length > 0) && (mobileNo.length > 0) && (EmpEmail.length > 0) && (EmpID.length > 0) && (UserCampusName != 0)) {
            console.log('up')
            $('#SubmitUserRole').removeAttr('disabled');
        }
        else {
            console.log('down')
            $('#SubmitUserRole').attr('disabled', 'disabled');
        }
    })

})
```

You can check as many inputs in `if-else`. In the above code I am not checking the textarea validation but you can modify it accordingly.